# Accordion/Modal not at the top using ionic

Tags: dictionary, mobile, ionic-framework

Got a screen for a map application that I need to implement using ionic
It has a map and a list that allows to see a part of the map. 
Trying to emulate a native behaviour I need to show the map when clicking on it, moving the list down. 
Any clue how to deal with it?

[image: Notes List]

Answer (score 1):

So this is a little out of the box but you did not post any code so I am just going to wing it. You can use a modal with a transparent div at the top that has a closeModal click event on it. like this: 
also check out the [playground](http://play.ionic.io/app/c8f75d7acafd)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane >
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="has-header" ng-controller="main">
        <button class="button button-assertive" ng-click="openModal()">I'm a button</button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
    <script id="my-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div style="filter:alpha(opacity=50); opacity:0.5;height: 70px;" ng-click="closeModal()">........</div>
  <ion-modal-view style="height: 90%; top: 10%;">

    <ion-header-bar>
      <h1 class="title">My Modal title</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      Hello!
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
</script>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic']).controller('main', function($ionicModal, $scope){
   $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
  //Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.modal.remove();
  });
  // Execute action on hide modal
  $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
    // Execute action
  });
  // Execute action on remove modal
  $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
    // Execute action
  });
});
```

Comment: Is a good idea but the the cons I see are:

* I'll need to wrap a navigation inside a modal 

* Looks a bit weird on ipad, perfect on iPhone although

Comment: Ah so are you wanting to use this same behavior for a list? I can probably get that working to. It may just be as simple as using ng-class to make the header transparent when the list is being shown. However, I think a modal is the only thing thing that shows up over something else. For I pad you may just be able to edit the modal so that it occupies the entire screen like it does on phones.